# How to include .ps files in latex and put three of them with text in one page?

Tags: graphics

I have `.ps` files, I want to prepare one pdf page, Then I want to show my files (`.ps` images) in the page in a way that divide the page to four section the top left section contains the text (e.g name, snr, time ... of my files) and the other three sections content my graph which is my `ps` file themselves.
How would I be able to do that?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\newpage
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[c][0.4\textheight][c]{\linewidth}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item name  hjjk
  \item snr  1522
  \item obser time  25885
  \end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}

\begin{subfigure}[!htbp]{0.6\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{10_freq_phase.png}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{10_pulse_profile}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[]{0.6\textwidth}
\centering
\vspace{0pt}% set the real top as the top
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{10_sub_int}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems like you have at least one PNG image. You can't mix PNG and PS, but you can mix PNG and PDF. So, convert the PS files to PDF and then you can compile with PDFLaTeX.

Comment: @Werner I'm using png here just as a test but my desire is to use ps files to do my process.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass{article} %
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} %
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\newpage
\begin{figure} [!htbp]
\begin{minipage}[c][0.4\textheight][c]{0.45\linewidth}
 \begin{enumerate}[wide = 0pt]
 \item name hjjk
 \item snr 1522
 \item obser time 25885
 \end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
%%
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{10_freq_phase.png}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\vspace*{-6ex }

\begin{subfigure}[c]{0.45\textwidth}
 \centering \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{10_pulse_profile}
\caption{}
 \end{subfigure}
 \qquad
\begin{subfigure}[c]{0.45\textwidth}
\centering \vspace{0pt}% set the real top as the top
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{10_sub_int}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you very much, could you tell me how to get rid of the border in the resultant image and fill the page with the image and the text without borders?

Comment: @abubakryagob: The border comes the `showframe` option of `geometry` – I used it to check the figure didn't overflow in the margin, it should be removed for the final document. I don't understand very well your second question: what do you mean exactly with ‘*fill* the page’ (unless you  just wanted to insist on removing the border?).

Comment: Yes I meant that (just to remove the border) and I figured it out, Thanks :  ). My real concern now is how to include the ps file?

Comment: Are  they  .ps or an .eps files?

Comment: They are .ps files

Comment: @abubakryagob: Which means they fill a full page, even if the image itself is smaller. You should first convert them to the `.eps` format (i.e. with a bounding box), then convert the .eps format to `.pdf`.  The `epspdf` utility, on CTAN, does a very good job for that (there's a graphic interface, `epspdftk`. The windows version is `epspdf-setup`.